# Printf called before scanf inside forked process in C

Tags: c, scanf, stdin

I came across a problem using scanf inside a new process, created with fork(). Scanf is not blocked, so printf is called over and over.
 Here is a sample of the code:

```
int main(int argc,char *argv[])
{
    switch(fork()) {
        case 0:
            while(1) {
                char buffer[100];
                scanf("%s",buffer);
                printf("Input was %s\n",buffer);
            }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Does anybody know how to solve this simple problem? (some parts of code are missing, I shrinked the code to a minimum for this problem)

Comment: Your new process doesn't have any interfaces, so scanf cannot scan.

Comment: how can i attach interface to it? @Joshpbarron

Comment: Why don't you scan in the father process?

Comment: I have to have two child processes, one client, one server, and client will scan and send to server. so a child must scan...

Comment: the `scanf()` function does not block, ever.  When calling `scanf()`, always check the returned value (not the parameter value) to assure the operation was successful.

Comment: when calling `fork()`, the child process needs to call `exit()` and the parent process much not be allowed to exit before the child process.  If the parent process exits first, then the child process becomes a `zombie` process.  A zombie process is very difficult to kill without rebooting the computer.  Suggest calling `wait()` or `waitpid() in the parent process so the parent does not exit before the child.  Remember that `fork()` returns 3 different conditions and the code must allow for all three conditions

Comment: When call `scanf()` with a `%s` format specifier, always include a `max characters` modifier so the input cannot overrun the input buffer.  Such input buffer overrun results in undefined behavior and can lead to a seg fault event.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is in the code that you commented out to make the minimal example, running this works perfectly fine

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc,char *argv[])
{
    switch(fork()) {
        case 0:
            while(1) {
                char buffer[100];
                scanf("%s",buffer);
                printf("Input was %s\n",buffer);
            }
            break;
        default:
            sleep(100);
            break;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

My guess is that with your full code around your `fork` call there is also some closing of files to create the subprocess and detach it from the terminal -- it is the closing of stdin and detachment from the terminal that makes you scanf fail.

Comment: The fork is not detached from the terminal, but the shell reopens a new stdin to read the next command and the previous one is closed

Comment: Yes -- fork in it self does not close anything -- I was refering to the part of the code that he had commented out -- will try to see if I can clarify

Answer (score 0):

The real problem is that the parent process returns immediately. The shell then takes the standard input to read a new command. You can easily demonstate it with a short sleep in parent:

```
switch(fork()) {
    case 0: 
        while(1) {
            char buffer[100];
            int cr = scanf("%s",buffer);
            printf("Input was %s (%d)\n",buffer, cr);
            if (cr <= 0) break;
        }
    }
    break;
default:
    sleep(5);
    printf("Done\n");
}
```

During the 5 seconds where the parent sleeps, you can normally interact with the child. Then when the parent exits, the input for the child is closed and `scanf` returns -1.